# Can i have a vsphere metric as both tags and fields in telegraf?

Tags: vsphere, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I Need to perform count of tags like vm, datastore, host , cluster .
show tag values cardinality from  with key="clustername" where dcname = ''
This query takes a lot of time to process, as we have huge data. Was thinking , the problem could be solved if these metric were fields. i could just use count on them. but we need them as tags also. 
Is there a better solution to this ?